# Is there any way for a compound literal to have variable length in c99?

Tags: c, c99, compound-literals

I know that arrays with lengths determined at runtime are possible by declaring the array normally:

```
char buf[len];
```

and I know that I can declare an array as a compound litral and assign it to a pointer midway:

```
char *buf;
....
buf = (char[5]) {0};
```

However, combining the two doesn't work (is not allowed by the standard).

My question is: Is there any way to achieve the effect of of the following code? (note `len`)

```
char *buf;
....
buf = (char[len]) {0};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is `memset` not an option ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. I'm trying to achieve what the first code segment does (dynamically allocate memory on the stack) using compound literal notation.

Comment: If you don't care about writing valid portable C, `alloca` could be used...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The language explicitly prohibits this

> **6.5.2.5 Compound literals**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> **1** The type name shall specify an object type or an array of unknown
> size, but not a variable length array type.

If you need something like this, you'd have to use a named VLA object instead of compund literal. However, note that VLA types do not accept initializers, meaning that you can't do this

```
char buf[len] = { 0 }; // ERROR for non-constant `len`
```

(I have no idea what the rationale behind this restriction is.)

So, in addition to using a named VLA object you'll have to come up with some way to zero it out, like a `memset` or an explicit cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response (and const. edits ;) ). However, I'm aware that the standard prohibits it. I'm trying to avoid littering my code with temp variables and was hoping that there is something with a syntax that is as convenient as compound literals.

Comment: Thought so, it's a shame since variable compound literals should technically be possible because VLAs are. Hopefully the next standard..

Comment: @seininn. I agree with your use for temporaries. I think the ideal construct for this use would be just the first part of the compound literal. Simply (float [n]){} with the empty initializer because all we need is space and auto-initializing a variable length array is probably of limited utility anyway. It conflicts with the gcc {} extension but zero init wouldn't be a horrible deal either.