# Getting the size of varargs in C?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am trying to convert some Java code into C. The Java code goes like this:

```
public static int minimum( int... minimum ) {

    assert( minimum.length > 0 );

    if ( minimum.length > 0 )
     .... // some code that i am able to translate to C without any hassle
}
```

Now I understand how to have varargs in C by using the `stdarg.h` header and using the macros provided. However I am stuck doing the `minimum.length` part.

I have tried `strlen` but the terminal is giving me an incompatible integer to pointer conversion warning. Is there any way in C where I can replicate the same thing that Java does?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the end of va\_arg list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356030/how-to-determine-the-end-of-va-arg-list)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not directly, as pointed out by @MichaelBurr, you need to pass the number of elements or use a sentinel.

An indirect way to do this is using compound literals:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define minimum(...) fnminimum(sizeof((int []) {__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int), __VA_ARGS__)

static int fnminimum(int n, ...)
{
    int num, min = INT_MAX;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, n);
    while (n--) {
        num = va_arg(ap, int);
        if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return min;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;

    printf("%d\n", minimum(2, 30, 7, a++, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

Another (ugly) method using [NARGS macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920577/casting-all-parameters-passed-in-macro-using-va-args) (limited to N args):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define NARGS_SEQ(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,N,...) N
#define NARGS(...) NARGS_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define minimum(...) fnminimum(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

static int fnminimum(int n, ...)
{
    int num, min = INT_MAX;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, n);
    while (n--) {
        num = va_arg(ap, int);
        if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return min;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", minimum(2, 30, 7, 1, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Rev 2 `#define minimum...` is very interesting!  It appear to evaluate args only once.  Good if code was `printf("%d\n", minimum(a++, 30, 7, 1, 4));`

Comment: Thank you @chux, edited. And yes, `sizeof` [doesn't evaluate the args](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8225813/1606345) (except when it is a variable length array)

Comment: ... and a _compound literal_ [cannot be a VLA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14550583/2410359).  Nice solution.  (I think this solution should be listed before the ugly one.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in way to get the number of vararg arguments passed in C.

You need to do one of the following:

- pass in a count explicitly,
- pass in a count implicitly (as `printf()` does via the number of conversion specifiers)
- or use a sentinel value (such as `NULL` or `0`) to indicate the end of  the vararg list

I have seen schemes that use macros and the `__VA_ARGS__` identifier to automatically place a sentinel at the end of the varargs list when calling a function.

Comment: If i were to employ the third option then the code would be like this: `assert ( NULL != va_arg( vaList, int) )` assuming `vaList` as our argument list?

Comment: @Saad: no.  You wouldn't be using `assert`.  As you pop each value off the list (`va_arg(args, type)`), you'd check to see whether the value popped is the sentinel value — with a regular `if` statement.

Comment: `NULL` is not a good choice.  C does not specify its _type_ and `va_arg()` needs to know the type.  A sentinel value needs to certainly have the same type as  arguments.  `foo_i(1,2,NULL);  foo_sa("1","2",NULL); foo_sb("1","2",0);` are all problematic. `foo_sc("1","2",(char*)0);` and `foo_sd("1","2",(char*)NULL);` are OK